# How does an x86 CPU knows which ISR to run based on a hardware interrupt

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, hardware

How does an x86 CPU knows which Interrupt Service Routine to run based on a hardware interrupt? I mean, is their some kind of mapping between a hardware interrupt number and a particular Interrupt Service Routine. If so, what is this mapping called and who or what loads it into memory?

Comment: Exactly, each interrupt has a number, and for each different ISR is invoked. More info here: http://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupts . Look for IDT, "Interrupt Descriptor Table"

Comment: Interrupts are stored in the IDT (in protected mode) or the start of memory (in real mode).  You can remap hardware interrupts through the interrupt controller. The BIOS (firmware) loads the initial set of handlers and the OS sets up its own later.